# How would you request data to a webservice?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app which connects to a Symfony2 project (PHP).
This app is kinda like a Notes app. So every user will have his **private list of notes**.

When I request for the list of notes for the logged user, which info do I've to send? 
We're not able to create a session, so we can't "remember" if the user that previously logged in, is the same that is requesting to list all the notes for X user.

So every time I want to receive some "personal" data, do I've to send user and password? Somehow, everytime I do a request to the webservice, I've to tell who I am, by sending username and password over and over again.

Is there any better way to do this?

I don't know if I explained myself correctly. Any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a way to do it without creating a session? Or are you actually asking how to create a session?

Comment: @rhnoble can sessions be actually created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you create a session with a session ID held in the cookie.  THen you reuse the same Http client for each request, so the cookie is kept around.  That way you don't need to send the login information each time.

Comment: That should be... Any tutorial around?

Comment: Haven't done it myself, but check out the docs http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html